# Can I do a conditional & assignment at the same time using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I want to do this pseudo code:

```
if plan = some_api.get_plan
  return plan
else
  return 'free'
end
```

How can I most elegantly do this in Rails? I want to minimise calls to `some_api.get_plan`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the simplest code is:

```
return some_api.get_plan || 'free'
```

But since assignments return the assigned value, you can do assignment and a conditional at the same time (and in fact, I do it all the time to make my code more concise).

Comment: You probably ought to `return` that…

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean OR operator to do this:

```
return (plan = some_api.get_plan) || 'free'
```

It will return the value of lefthand expression (an assignment in this case) if it is not `nil` or `false`, else it will return value of right expression.

Please note that assignment is only required if `plan` is not a local variable but is a `plan=` setter method (like `attr_writer :plan` or `def plan= val`). If this is not the case `return some_api.get_plan || 'free'` is enough.

Comment: Does this construct have a name?

Comment: @cjm2671, yes, this is boolean OR operator. I updated my answer.